# Pointer to class member as template argument

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, pointer-to-member, class-template

How to implement a template that gets a class and a pointer to a member of this class?

I want to template a sort of `Accessor` of the form

```
template<??? T, ??? P>
class Accessor
{
    // ...

    T& setMember(const Vector3d& point)
    {
        T& obj = getObject<T>();
        obj.*P = point;
        return obj;
    }
};
```

Here, there is a class `T` with a member `P`, both template variables. I know that `P` is always of type `Vector3d`. But I have to stay within C++17. Of course, if you have a C++20 technique... I want to know!

Also, `Accessor` does not have any reference to a `T` object. But the function `getObject` magically handles it here. Therefore do not need to care here.

I'd like to use it like this:

```
class Accessed
{
    Vector3d one_point;
    Vector3d another_point;

    class OneAccessor : public Accessor<&one_point> {};
    class AnotherAccessor : public Accessor<&another_point> {};
}
```

Notice the format : `public Accessor<&one_point>`.

Maybe `public Accessor<&Accessed::one_point>`.

I would prefer

```
public Accessor<one_point> // or 
public Accessor<Accessed::one_point>
```

without the `&`. I'd like `Accessed::` to be inferred.

If you have an answer to my problem that you want to deliver, I would very much like to see it.

Comment: The design seems overly complicated at first glance. How do you want to use the `Accessed` class and `OneAccessor`/`AnotherAccessor` classes?

Comment: You can use `Accessor<&Accessed::one_point>` but then where will the `Accessed` pointer come from when you call `setMember`?  Are you willing to pass the `Accessed*` to the `Accessor` constructor?  I suspect that if we saw the larger picture, we'd want to solve it a completely different way.

Comment: @JohnZwinck: No, I do not want to pass it to the constructor. Please, take it as if you were reading "cppreference.com". They write things like `template<auto...> struct C {};` and nobody argues. :-)

Comment: @JohnZwinck: Yes... `Accessor<&Accessed::one_point>` is nice. But how do I declare the template for `Accessor`?

Comment: *They write things like template<auto...> struct C {}; and nobody argues.* Sure, but their examples actually makes sense and are self-explained, even if they are a bit hard to wrap your head around sometimes. Asking you to clarify your question is not the same as arguing.

Comment: @super: I do agree with you! But notice that: 1. My example actually makes sense. 2. The sentence "Accessor does not have any reference to a T object" makes my post self-explained in this specific case. But I do agree with you and @ JohnZwinck. I will try to post a bigger picture and then I will ping you both. I will have to expose my bad design (and myself!), though... and I will probably give you real reason to complain. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
template <typename T>
struct class_type;

template<typename T>
struct class_type<Vector3d T::*> {
    using type = T;
};

template<auto P>
struct Accessor
{
    using T = typename class_type<decltype(P)>::type;

    T& setMember(const Vector3d& point)
    {
        T& obj = getObject<T>();
        obj.*P = point;
        return obj;
    }
};

class Accessed
{
    Vector3d one_point;
    Vector3d another_point;

    class OneAccessor : public Accessor<&Accessed::one_point> {};
    class AnotherAccessor : public Accessor<&Accessed::another_point> {};
};
```

Another version using variables:

```
template<typename T>
struct Accessor
{
    Vector3d T::* p;

    constexpr Accessor(Vector3d T::* p) :p{p} {}

    T& setMember(const Vector3d& point)
    {
        T& obj = getObject<T>();
        obj.*p = point;
        return obj;
    }
};

struct Accessed
{
    Vector3d one_point;
    Vector3d another_point;

    static constexpr Accessor OneAccessor{&Accessed::one_point};
    static constexpr Accessor AnotherAccessor{&Accessed::another_point};
};
```

Comment: Okay... I didn't test it, yet... but I guess that if this works, it is what one is supposed to do whenever s/he attempts to `template<typename T> template<... something that uses T>`. :-)

Answer (score 4):

The class member type of passed class member pointer can be found by a trait. However, the syntax `Accessor<decltype(&Accessed::one_point)>` elimination, might require a deduction guide, which I leave it to you.

Assuming the `Accessor` would have an internal state for the member of the `Accessed`, you can round up a solution as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

using Vector3d = std::string; // just for test

template <typename T> struct member {};
// traits for member type
template<typename Class, typename Type>
struct member<Type Class::*> {
    using mem_type = Type;
    using class_type = Class;
};
// alias types for convenience
template<typename T> using class_type_t = typename member<T>::class_type;
template<typename T> using mem_type_t = typename member<T>::mem_type;

template<typename T> class Accessor
{
    T mMember;
public:
    explicit Accessor(T mem)
        : mMember{mem}
    {}
    auto setMember(const Vector3d& point);  
};

class Accessed
{
    Vector3d one_point;
    Vector3d another_point;
public:

    struct OneAccessor : public Accessor<decltype(&Accessed::one_point)> {
        OneAccessor()
            : Accessor<decltype(&Accessed::one_point)>{ &Accessed::one_point }
        {}
        auto test(const Vector3d& point);
    };
    auto getOne() const { return one_point;  }
};

template<typename T>
auto Accessor<T>::setMember(const Vector3d& point)
{
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<class_type_t<T>, Accessed>)
    {
        static class_type_t<T> obj{};
        obj.*mMember = point;
        return obj;
    }
}

auto Accessed::OneAccessor::test(const Vector3d& point)
{
    return this->setMember(point);
}

int main()
{
    Accessed::OneAccessor ob;
    auto var = ob.test("Hello world\n");
    std::cout << var.getOne();

    var = ob.test("Good bye\n");
    std::cout << var.getOne();
}
```

[See a live demo in godbolt.org](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/4q6h9Whfx)´

---

The following, leave it to the OP:

- I have tweaked a bit of the original code such as `Vector3d`, `getObject<T>()`, etc.
- There can be some more improvements done for the above, such as deduction guide or re-arrange some part of code, if valid.

Comment: I will finally find out what a "trait" is!!! <3

Comment: Thank you for your time, dedication and patience! Yours is certainly the most complete and carefully written answer. I will accept @krisz's answer because it is simpler and more direct. I have learned a lot. :-)

Answer (score 2):

I do not really understand your use case but to answer the question: it is possible to use a member function as a non-type parameter of a template. The following code illustrates the syntax:

```
#include <iostream>

class foo {
    int bar_;
public:
    void setBar(int n = 0) {
        bar_ = n;
    }
    int getBar() const {
        return bar_;
    }
};

template<typename T, void(T::*F)(int)>
class accessor {
    T& accessee_;
public:
    accessor(T& a) : accessee_(a) {};
    T& setMember(int n) {
        auto& obj = accessee_;
        (obj.*F)(n);
        return obj;
    }
};

int main()
{
    foo a_foo;
    accessor<foo, &foo::setBar> foo_accessor(a_foo);
    foo& ref_to_a_foo = foo_accessor.setMember(42);
    std::cout << ref_to_a_foo.getBar() << "\n";
}
```